# How to create default sample data for dev env in Symfony?

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony

## Context

I'm working with several people on a Symfony application.

## Problem

We would like to have a database filled automatically with sample data, to avoid creating it manually on each developer environment.

## Question

Is there an official way to do it or do we need to use `.sql` files we pass to each other to create sample data?

I've seen that's possible with the .net framework, that's why I ask for Symfony.

Comment: I would like to know why my question is downvoted. Searching "how to create [default] sample data in Symfony" did not helped me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Also there is another bundle called [AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle), which makes it very easy to generate different sets of data.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!